# How to change the background image of whole application

Tags: android

In my app,I have created 5 activity file correspond to 5 xml file.Now In first activity,I have put a button which navigate to another activity from where i can choose an image .Now I want that the image which is choosen will be attach in the background of the whole application.What i have to do?? please suggest me..

Answer (score 6):

Here is the way to set one common background to your application, modify it as per your requirement.

Make a style of your own as follows :

```
<style name="Background" parent="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar">
<item name="android:windowBackground">@android:color/black</item>
<item name="android:windowNoTitle">true</item>
```

Now in the manifest file do like this :

```
<application  android:theme="@style/Background"/>
```

Here is the global method for the theme updation, call this method with your activity context before setContentView in each activity

public static void setTheme(Context context) {

```
    SharedPreferences pref=context.getSharedPreferences("preference",0);
    int position= pref.getInt("BackgroundPosition", 0);

    switch (position) {
    case 0:

        context.setTheme(R.style.Background0);

        break;

    case 1:

        context.setTheme(R.style.Background1);

        break;

    case 2:

        context.setTheme(R.style.Background2);

        break;

    case 3:
        context.setTheme(R.style.Background3);
        break;

    case 4:
        context.setTheme(R.style.Background4);
        break;
    }
}
```

Thanks

Comment: how to change it when the value in settings will be changed?

Comment: this doesn't answer the OP question.

Comment: Yeah StinePike is correct..I want to change the background of whole application programatically after selecting a particular image..

Answer (score 0):

Save background image name (you can use SharedPreferences if you want the same image even after the app is dead.
Load it dynamically in every activity.

```
LinearLayout ll = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.blayout);
//This function will change background drawable, so place it where you want.
ll.setBackgroundDrawable(yourDrawableID);
```

Comment: its too bulky my dear..if i have more than 20 activities..Please suggest me the simple way.

Comment: @DeepakSharma, you are right. A real pain with 20 activities. You still can create a method for that purpose.

Comment: Is there a way in android to make a common code to set the background of whole application?

Comment: @StinePike has posted something that could be useful. Have you consider using android fragments since all activities share the same background?

Answer (score 0):

Lazy Ninja's answer seems a good one. But as you want some different you can try this.

**Disclaimer:** It is Just an experimental solution. Haven't tried it before. So need to be sure before implementation

Create a base activity and extends all of your activity where you can set the root layout of the activity. Set the layout in oncreate there. In BaseActivity ovverride the onresume. in the onresume set the background image accorind to the shared preference of setting page as Ninja suggested

**Code example**

```
public class BaseActivity extends Activity{

   private ViewGroup root;
   onResume(){
      root.setBackgroundImage();
   }

   public void setRoot(ViewGroup v){
      root = v;
   }

}


class A extends BaseActivity{
   onCreate(Bundle b){
      ....

      setRoot(pass the root view);
     ......
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I got the solution of my own question:-

```
    public static void setHomeSafeTheme(Context context) {

    SharedPreferences pref=context.getSharedPreferences(HomeSAFEPref.HomeSAFEPref,0);
    int position= pref.getInt("BackgroundPosition", 0);

    switch (position) {
    case 0:

        context.setTheme(R.style.Background0);

        break;

    case 1:

        context.setTheme(R.style.Background1);

        break;

    case 2:

        context.setTheme(R.style.Background2);

        break;

    case 3:
        context.setTheme(R.style.Background3);
        break;

    case 4:
        context.setTheme(R.style.Background4);
        break;
    }
}
```